Find area between the given curves f(x) and g(x)
If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two real functions given by $f(x)= -x^2 ( x^2 -8x + 16 )$ and $g(x) = | x - 2i |$ for  $(2i-1) \le x \le (2i+1)$, where $i = 0, 1, 2, 3$, then the area enclosed by the curves $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ in $xy$-plane from $x=0$ to $x=4$ is?
Now graphing $f(x)$ was an easy task but i'm confused on how to graph the $g(x)$, if anyone could guide me to graph $g(x)$, it would be great, also i don't intend to waste anyone's time so the guidance would suffice or a hint....

Is $i\in{0,1,2,3}$ only? Or did you mean to say it's any non-negative integer, i.e. $i\in{0,1,2,3,\ldots}$?

Yes i is 0,1,2,3 only

$g$ is a kind of sawtooth function in which a portion of $|x|$ is copied and translated to the right by $2$ units. See this plot

Thanks, i understand it now, area for f(x) is a simple integral + the 4 triangles by g(x)
